# Performing animations in Android

Tags: android-layout

In android can i put animations to each rows (view) of a List.  What I want o achieve that rows at even position should translate from left of screen and rows at odd positions should translate from right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the animations(using startAnimation) to each view of row in getView method of Adapter.